# How do I resolve a TesseractNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract in Python but I always end up with the following error:

```
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

However, pytesseract and Tesseract are installed on my system.

Example code that produces this error:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('1d.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

How do I resolve this TesseractNotFoundError?

Comment: Same issue getting for AWS lambda

Answer (score 126):

I got this error because I installed `pytesseract` with `pip` but forget to install the binary.

#### On Linux

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

#### On Mac

```
brew install tesseract
```

#### On Windows

download binary from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. then add `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'` to your script. (replace path of tesseract binary if necessary)

references:
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ (INSTALLATION section) and 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#installation

Comment: For Windows 64 bit, add pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

Comment: BOOM! Well done sir give that man a cookie!

Comment: Yess. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: for the record, installing tesseract as specified works on my ubuntu-based docker image as well

Answer (score 54):

I tried adding to the path variable like others have mentioned, but still received the same error. what worked was adding this to my script:

> pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

Comment: May be you have installed 64 bit version, Please check the below path if you have 
'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'. In case tesseract is available, change that line as below

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

Answer (score 21):

You are probably missing `tesseract-ocr` from your machine. Check the installation instructions here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

On a Mac, you can just install using homebrew:

`brew install tesseract`

It should run fine after that

Answer (score 17):

I'm running on a Mac OS and installed tesseract with brew so here's my take on this. Since pytesseract is just how you can access tesseract from python, you have to specify where tesseract is already on your computer.

*For Mac OS*

Try finding where the tesseract.exe is- if you installed it using
    **brew**, on your the terminal use:

```
>brew list tesseract
```

This should list where your tesseract.exe is, somewhere more or less like

```
> /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.02/bin/tesseract
```

[Then following their instructions](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

> pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.02/bin/tesseract'

should do the trick!

Answer (score 16):

Under Windows 10 OS environment, the following method works for me:

1. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki
   Download tesseract and install it. Windows version is available here:
   https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. Find script file `pytesseract.py` from `C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract` and open it.
   Change the following code from `tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'` to: `tesseract_cmd = 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'`
3. You may also need add environment variable `D:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/`

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 13):

> CAUTION: ONLY FOR WINDOWS

---

I came across this problem today and all the answers mentioned here helped me, but I personally had to dig a lot to solve it. So let me help all others by putting out the solution to it in a very simple form:

1. Download the executable 64 bit (32-bit if your computer is of 32
   bit) exe from [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki).

   (Name of the file would be tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0.20190526
   (alpha))

2. Install it. Let it install itself in the default C directory.
3. Now go to your Environment variable (Reach there by just searching it in the start menu or Go to `Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`)

a) Select PATH and then Edit it. Click on NEW and add the path where it is installed (Usually `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\`)

Now you will not get the error!

Comment: The "here" link that you have provided is broken, it is missing an "i" after "wik". I found the correct link after going to the module's website. Also, what should be the "Variable Name" when trying to add tesseract to the environment variables, i.e. PATH.

Comment: @tanmay_garg Thanks for pointing out the broken link. The variable name should be 'Path'. Let me explain you better:

When you go to Environment Variables, under System Variables you will find a variable named 'Path'. Double click on it and then click on New (once inside the Path), and then add the location path.

Comment: Ohh, I thought you meant that a new user variable had to be created! Got it thanks! Finally understood what adding a package to the "PATH" means ooff :)

Comment: @tanmay_garg Happy that I was able to help

Comment: Very instructive and the most clear answer to the problem for Windows users.

Answer (score 12):

For Mac:

1. Install Pytesseract (*pip install pytesseract* should work)
2. Install Tesseract **but only with homebrew, pip installation somehow doesn't work**. (*brew install tesseract*)
3. Get the path of brew installation of Tesseract on your device (*brew list tesseract*)
4. Add the path **into your code, not in sys path**. The path is to be added along with code, using pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<path received in step 3>' - (e.g. *pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.0.0_1/bin/tesseract'*)

This should work fine.

Answer (score 10):

One simple thing that actually worked for me in Jupyter Notebook, was using **double backslash** instead of a single backslash in the pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd path:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem. I hope you have installed from [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) and have also done `pip install pytesseract`.

If everything is fine you should see that the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR where tesseract.exe` is available.

Adding Path variable did not helped me, I actually added new variable with name `tesseract` in environment variables with a value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe`.

Typing `tesseract` in the command line should now work as expected by giving you usage informations. You can now use `pytesseract` as such (don't forget to restart your python kernel before running this!):

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

value=Image.open("text_image.png")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(value, config='')    
print("text present in images:",text)
```

enjoy!

Comment: Since the os is not specified in the question for Windows Users this will be the approved answer

Answer (score 7):

I face this same issue. I just use this command that will help me.

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Note that this will only work on Ubuntu.
`sudo` is a Unix exclusive command (Linux, Mac, Rasbian, etc.) while `apt` is Ubuntu specific.

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing the same error when I was trying to make a text-extractor using pytesseract, but the solution was there in installation instructions for  **pytesseract** in pypi site: [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)
There are many alternatives to avoid the error,
But, adding one more parameter in the method **pytesseract.image_to_string** solved it for me, like

```
tessdata_dir_config = "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata"
output = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Comment: Thank you! Only this helped me. I use: pytesseract, jupyter notebook, conda env with only ipykernel installed (jupyter not installed in this env), ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

The following three commands will do the needful :

```
sudo apt update
# This will update your packages
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
# This will install OCR
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
# This will add it as development dependency
```

Comment: Nice @Shivam Bharadwaj , I did it same way

Answer (score 3):

You can download tesseract-ocr setup using the following link,

[Tesseract for windows](https://excellmedia.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tesseract-ocr-alt/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe)

Then add new variable with name tesseract in environment variables with value C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe

Answer (score 2):

Install tesseract from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and add the path of tesseract.exe to the **Path** environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have different versions of Python installed, ensure that the installed Tesseract is on the same Python version.

`which pip3` shows you the path to the pip3 installation and `which python3` shows the corresponding path to the Python installation.

Ensure that these two are the same.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs under windows (at least in tesseract version 3.05) when the current directory is on a different drive from where tesseract is installed.

Something in tesseract is expecting data files to be in \Program Files... (rather than C:\Program Files, say). So if you're not on the same drive letter as tesseract, it will fail. It would be great if we could work around it by temporarily changing drives (under windows only) to the tesseract installation drive before executing tesseract, and changing back after.
Example in your case: You can copy yourmodule_python.py to "C/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/" and RUN!

Answer (score 2):

> There Are few steps to set the path
>
> 1:goto this "https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki"
>
> 2:download the latest installers
>
> 3:install it
>
> 4: set the path in system variables such as "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" or 
>      "C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Tesseract-OCR"
>
> 5 : open CMD type "tesseract" and some output except "not regonized type errors"

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu under flask webframework this should be working

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"/usr/bin/tesseract"
img = Image.open(picture_name)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing

```
from tesseract import image_to_string
```

Don't import from pytesseract

Comment: I used this statement but got an error "ImportError: cannot import name image_to_string". I  tried solving this error but still struggling with it

Comment: I have the same problem as OP. If from tesseract import image_to_string, then: 


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-25-e72b4376f6a2>", line 3, in <module>
    from tesseract import image_to_string

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 34
    print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? If so, can you add a link to the Python module you are referring to? It seems incorrect, since [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) is an optical character recognition (OCR) tool, while [tesseract](https://pypi.org/project/tesseract/) is for "computing concentrations of simulated dark matter halos from volume info for particles generated using Voronoi tesselation". That tesseract library only runs on Python 2 and does not include an `image_to_string` method.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, just add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR` to your path variable. 
If it still does not work, add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata` to your path variable in a new line. And do not forget to restart your computer after adding the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Windows and needed to develop a PDF parser but adding a new environment variable via `sysdm.cpl` alone did not work. For other Windows user, I strongly suggest adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR` to your `profile.ps1` as well (if using Powershell that is).

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake -- I knew I had to open/close my cmd to get the updated path to reflect. Using Jupyter Notebook I had to shutdown the client and re-initialize it also.

Answer (score 0):

Just run these command if you are using linux,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

then run this,

```
python -m pip install tesseract tesseract-ocr pytesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked by putting single quote

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd =r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

actually putting inside double quotes was automatically inserting unwanted chracter

Answer (score 0):

This is my path

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"  # your path may be different
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my path from:

```
path_to_tesseract = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
to 
path_to_tesseract = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

issue resolved for me