# Tesseract using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I was writing a code to extract text from images using "pytesseract" library in Python. This is my code

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("Figure_3.png"))
print(text)
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)
ax1.imshow("Figure3.png")
```

I just store the text in the image to a variable and display the original image.

I am getting the following error

```
TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

I have added Tesseract to my environment variable. I don't know where I have gone wrong. I don't have any problem in importing ass well.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/tesseract-not-found-error

Comment: yes I did its not working

Comment: How did you install Tesseract and what is your os?

Comment: I downloaded it from Tesseract at UB Manheim. I am using windows 10