# Tesseract installation in Google colaboratory

Tags: tesseract, google-colaboratory

I have installed tesseract in Google colab using the command

```
!pip install tesseract
```

But when I run the command

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('cropped_img.png'))
```

I get the below error:

> TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tesseract Not Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/tesseract-not-found-error)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'`

This should solve the TesseractNotFoundError.

Comment: Using `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = ( r'/usr/bin/tesseract' )` worked for me. Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62905505/8664401

Comment: how to add this ? i mean where to add it ?

Answer (score 14):

There could be a number of reasons for this, but normally it is because you do not have the `C` library available for tesseract. Even though `pytesseract` is required, it is only half of the solution.

You essentially need to install both the tesseract package for linux, along with the Python binding.

This would essentially be the solution:

```
! apt install tesseract-ocr
! apt install libtesseract-dev
```

The above installs the required dependencies for `pytesseract`. This is very important, especially the `!` without which you cannot install directly to the underlying operating system.

The remainder of the process is relatively simple:

```
! pip install Pillow
! pip install pytesseract
```

This installs the Python binding.

The remainder is fairly simple and all you need to do is `import`!

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageEnhance, ImageFilter, Image
```

Then you can let the magic happen.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This is really helpful when I am using Google Colab instead of my own MacBook. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 7):

You have to install the tesseract engine first, before using the pytesseract wrapper. You can install the engine on Google colab using:

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

You can find a sample at:

https://github.com/labdeeman7/document-ocr/blob/master/classification%20via%20NLP%20and%20information%20extraction.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install `pytesseract` rather than `tesseract`.

Here's an example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zduW1Hxv7Z_pwMFGjVauhs1dTlvZByCy

Comment: I have installed pytesseract with the command "!pip install pytesseract" ,still getting the same error. Can you please provide an example of reading image with pytesseract in the above notebook.

Answer (score 1):

after installation you need to specify path to tessaract then only it will work

to specify path in colab, you can run

```
import pytesseract 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (r'/bin/tesseract')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr

!pip install pytesseract
```

Run these two commands in your colab cell before using tesseract. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

At first run this code in a cell :

```
!pip3 install pytesseract
```

After that RESTART RUNTIME then run this code in another cell:

```
!apt install tesseract-ocr
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Please always write your code like ```code``` do have it distinguished from the rest of the text. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set the path to the Tesseract binary (adjust this based on your system)
# pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/path/to/pytesseract'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = ( r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract' )
```

and this is the default location that the pytessaract is getting stored

```
import pytesseract
```

and then run the

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = ( r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including some that have been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?