# Using layoutlm-document-qa on colab and install Tesseract

Tags: google-colaboratory, tesseract, huggingface

I am using [impira/layoutlm-document-qa](https://huggingface.co/impira/layoutlm-document-qa) on colab as shown [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ESbsCmaup6E5p3q73BS55qYJlmaeabvu?usp=sharing).

https://huggingface.co/impira/layoutlm-document-qa

When I run, I got this error although I have already installed tesseract-oc, libtesseract-dev, Pillow and pytesseract.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-09498387767d> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 )
      8 
----> 9 nlp(
     10     "https://templates.invoicehome.com/invoice-template-us-neat-750px.png",
     11     "What is the invoice number?"

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/document_question_answering.py in preprocess(self, input, lang, tesseract_config)
    263             elif "words" in image_features and "boxes" in image_features:
    264                 words = image_features.pop("words")[0]
--> 265                 boxes = image_features.pop("boxes")[0]
    266             elif image is not None:
    267                 if not TESSERACT_LOADED:

ValueError: If you provide an image without word_boxes, then the pipeline will run OCR using Tesseract, but pytesseract is not available
```

How shall I resolve that issue? I have been searching through stackoverflow and saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696446/tesseract-installation-in-google-colaboratory).

Should I add `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'`? If so, where shall I add?

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing an error despite installing Tesseract-OCR `!apt install tesseract-ocr` and pytesseract `!pip install pytesseract`, make sure to restart the runtime after installing these dependencies.

In Colab, navigate to the "Runtime" menu and choose "Restart Runtime."

No extra configuration is needed.