# Error! The command "tesseract" was not found. (PHP thiagoalessio)

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I am encountering this error message

> Error! The command "tesseract" was not found.

However, tesseract and tesseract php wrapper is already installed.

When I run below,

```
echo (new TesseractOCR())->version();
```

it shows the version.  When I run this,

```
$ocr = new TesseractOCR(asset('uploads/img.jpg'));
$ocr->run();
```

the error shows.

Please help.

Thank you!

my Code

```
public function creditCardOrderProcessImage() 
{
    $image = Input::file('image');
    $name = time().'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $file = $image->move('uploads/', $name);

    echo '<img src ='.asset('uploads/'.$name).' />';

    $ocr = new TesseractOCR(asset('uploads/'.$name));
    $ocr->run();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre just trying to define the image path? [See](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php)

```
 $ocr = new TesseractOCR();
 $ocr->image('uploads/img.jpg');
 $ocr->run();
```

Comment: So how should it be done?
what I am doing is an input type="file" when onchange runs an ajax which process the OCR.
I tried not saving the image and getting it through $_files.
but still error occurs.

Comment: try $ocr = new TesseractOCR(storage_path('uploads/img.jpg'));

Comment: Already tried it and still doesn't work.
It still says tesseract is not installed,

Additional info in error message : 
he current $PATH is C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\php;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin' (length=358)

Comment: I am not sure about your environment. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/tesseract-not-found-error

Comment: I am currently using laravel 4.2 w/php 5.6

Comment: Youre on windows it looks like. You might be missing "\tesseract.exe" in your path after "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR;"

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I added this 
executable('C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe')
on the code and it worked!