# TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR esseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path

Tags: anaconda, python-tesseract

I run Python via an Anaconda/Spyder console environment
Version - 3.7.2 (default, Jan  2 2019, 17:07:39) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

I have followed the recommendations from this stackoverflow post:
[Tesseract Not Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/tesseract-not-found-error)

for dealing with the following error:

TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR  esseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path

Notice that a portion of the path is missing.  This is installed at:
C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe

In my pytesseract.py file I changed the path as suggested to:
tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe

This didn't solve my issue and resulting in the error message now with part of the path string missing.

TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR  esseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path

So I played around with this and added a second \ as below:

Python code:

tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

Now this works fine and read and successfully converted an entire newspaper page image into string text.

Nothing in the recommendations I followed originally indicated I had to add a second \ to the path, and I don't understand myself why I need to do this.

I would be grateful for any guidance on why this occurred?