# I'm receiving "ModuleNotFoundError" when importing pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, macos-catalina, python-tesseract

I have a problem when I use the pytesseract library with python
I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.5
And I'm using an environment to run openCV Library and it works just fine, I installed pytesseract using homebrew using this command - with the environment active -:

```
brew install tesseract
```

and I checked the version of tesseract it shows v4.1.1
So I'm not sure where is the mess up

Comment: That command installs tesseract but not the python module

Comment: did you try "pip install pytesseract"  ?

Comment: @Gautamrk should I do this after using the brew command, it won't make any conflicts?

Comment: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'   i searched a bit . i think you are supposed to add pytesseract to your path or just add this one liner in your script  https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/how-do-i-resolve-a-tesseractnotfounderror  give this a read