# Error: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError- tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to try and run some pytesseract related programs. I have followed all the steps i.e

1. Installed windows binaries and dependencies from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. `pip install pytesseract`
3. Changed pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd, straight from the path of tesseract.exe .

I'm still getting the TesseractNotFoundError. What I can do to fix it?

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"D:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract"
content = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r'D:/test.jpeg'))
print(content)
```

Comment: Try type `tesseract -v` in your cmd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve a TesseractNotFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/how-do-i-resolve-a-tesseractnotfounderror)